# python is saying "self" is the "missing required positional argument" when called with asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'll try show all the functions that are being used here:

```
def main():
    peers = [*list with many peerIDs*]
    asyncio.run(async_peerImport.importPeers(peers))
```

```
async def importPeers(peers):
    dividedPeers = divideList(peers, 250)  # this is just a function I made to split lists into lists of smaller lists
    for peers in dividedPeers:
        await asyncio.gather(*[importPeer(peerID) for peerID in peers])

async def importPeer(peerID):
    fetchPeerDataTask = asyncio.create_task(async_requests.fetchPeerData(peerID))
    getTorStatusTask = asyncio.create_task(async_requests.fetchPeerData(peerID))
    peerData = await fetchPeerDataTask
    torStatus = await getTorStatusTask
    if peerData is not None and torStatus is not None:
        db.upsertPeer(peerID, torStatus, peerData)  # the function in question
        print("peer imported:", peerID)
```

```
class db:
    def upsertPeer(self, peerID, torStatus, peerData):
        try:
            sql = "INSERT INTO peers (peerID, torStatus, peerData) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
            self.cursor.execute(sql, [peerID, torStatus, json.dumps(peerData)])
            print("peer inserted")
        except psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation:
            sql = "UPDATE peers SET torStatus = %s, peerData = %s WHERE peerID = %s;"
            self.cursor.execute(sql, [torStatus, json.dumps(peerData), peerID])
            print("peer updated")
        finally:
            self.connection.commit()
```

Hopefully you can see what should be happening? If it is more difficult than I thought then tell me and I'll add a bunch of comments.
I don't see a reason for this not to work, but when I run it, I get this error:

```
  File "c:\path\async_peerImport.py", line 25, in importPeer
    db.upsertPeer(peerID, torStatus, peerData)
TypeError: upsertPeer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'peerData'
```

I tried adding some random object into the first position and moved all the other arguments up (total of 4), and it said that object `has no attribute 'connection'`. I have also run this `upsertPeer()` on its own and it does work with those 3 arguments. I am completly lost here. Am I doing something wrong?

Again, if anything I have tried to explain doesn't make sense just tell me and I'll try better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This bit:

```
class db:
    def upsertPeer(self, peerID, torStatus, peerData):
        # code here
```

defines an *instance method* of a class.  In order to access it, you need to access it through an instance of the db class, which might look like

```
my_db = db()
my_db.upsertPeer(peerId, torStatus, peerData)
```

In which case the value of `self` is `my_db` and it is implicitly passed without any intervention from you.

If you are attempting to make a class method, which can be used in the way your code does, try this:

```
class db:
    @classmethod
    def upsertPeer(cls, peerID, torStatus, peerData):
        # code here
```

Note that there's still an implicit first argument, but it's the `db` class object, not an instance of it.

Comment: Ah thanks. It isn't quite what you said but it is my fault. I called the db object db (the same name as the class). And because importPeer() is in a different python file (it was imported to the first one), it didn't have the same database object. I have called the class something different now and for each python file I have made the same db object. I guess a much better way to do this would be to pass the object into each function which needs it.